# switch to Iframe with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, iframe

How do i switch to a iframe with selenium, i'm trying to scrap data, but today the website updated and add a iframe. Now i didnt know how to switch and enter in the iframe to collect the data.

thats the iframe =

```
<iframe _ngcontent-xyi-c154="" type="text/html" frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="auto" src="https://direct.argusmedia.com/integration/price/pricedata" style="height: 2808px;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use an XPath to locate the iframe element first

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//iframe[@src='https://direct.argusmedia.com/integration/price/pricedata']")
```

Then switch_to the iframe

```
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

To switch back to the Parent Frame you can use the following line of code:

```
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
```

To switch back to the Top Level Browsing Context / Top Window you can use the following line of code:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

//Wait for frame
can you try adding a wait for frame

```
 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//iframe[@src='https://direct.argusmedia.com/integration/price/pricedata']')))
```

Comment: the error below apears to me:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //iframe[@src='https://direct.argusmedia.com/integration/price/pricedata']

But i look in the HTLM end there is that element, now i have no idea what can i do

Comment: can you try adding a wait for frame, updated above answer, to wait for frame then switch to it

Comment: i saw that i'm looking for the wrong iframe. I just change the "src='direct.argusmedia.com/integration/".
Thank you so much!